# Google Chorme update is always 48MB

Tags: updates, google-chrome

Google chrome ships update almost every week, the size is mostly 48MB.

**Questions**

1. Is it the full updated chorme every week?
2. Cannt Google ship patches to updated like it does for Windows?

Comment: You can see when versions are released [here](http://googlechromereleases.blogspot.com/).

Comment: @Nattgew: He's not asking *when* Chrome is updated; he's asking if the full Chrome package is re-downloaded each week and if it's possible to use debdiffs instead.

Comment: To the people who marked this as off-topic: how on earth is this off-topic!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because Google Chrome uses deb packages in the distribution, the full Chrome package will be downloaded for each release. In using deb packages and the `dpkg` framework, it's not possible to use the patching system that it uses on Windows.

Comment: Is deb community thinking to change this? Worldover this must TB of unnecessary data transfer every week.

Comment: Well, Chrome stable isn't updated every week. A new release is published every 6 weeks, but there may be some security/stability updates in between (there was one two days ago). Chrome beta and dev, however, *are* updated roughly every week. Also, note that this doesn't only apply for Chrome; there are many packages in Ubuntu's repo that could benefit from downloading diffs instead of the full package. However, this would involve server resources to generate the diffs for each package and for `apt` and `dpkg` to be patched to allow using diffs.